# How to read 2-byte float in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

Seems there are a lot of half float questions in other languages, but could not find one for Erlang.

So, I have a 2-byte float as part of a longer binary pattern input.  I tried to use pattern matching like `<<AFloat:16/float>>` and got warning/error in compiler, while using 32/float produced no warning.

Question is: What workaround is there in Erlang to convert the 2-byte binary into float?

I saw the other elaborate bit processing answer to "reading from binary file in Erlang", and do not know if it is required in this case.

*** Thanks for the answers below.  I shall try them out later ***

-- two sets of sample input: EF401C3FEA3F, 1242C341C341

Comment: my Erlang input pattern got truncated.  << AFloat:16/float>>

Comment: Correction/Clarification for above question:  Input pattern is NOT 2-byte float in binary, but in HEX, if that matters.

Comment: Could you give an example of such a float, both as it appears in the binary and the value you want to convert it to? You can [edit] your question and add the example.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Erlang does not support float widths other than 32 and 64 (at least currently), but I can't seem to find any documentation that says this explicitly.

Update: I checked the implementation of the bit syntax, and it definitely only handles 32 and 64 bit floats. This should really be better documented.

Update again: added to documentation upstream now.

Final update: Just saw your note about hex input. If you solve that as a first step, transforming the hex string H to a binary B with the actual data bytes, you can use the following to repack the data as 32-bit floats (a simple transformation), and then extract those the normal way:

```
Floats = [F || <<F:32/float>> <- [<<S:1,(E+(127-15)):8,(M bsl 13):23>> || <<S:1,E:5,M:10>> <- B]]
```

Comment: Hi @RichardC, it was my first idea to make a direct transformation of the format. In fact it works for nomal floats, but with this simple transformation, it fails for sub normal and for 0. I didn't check the result for nan, qnan and infinity. it is why I made the evaluation passing via integers and arithmetic operations.

Comment: @Pascal Yes, you can probably add handling of the corner cases to this transformation. Too keep the precision intact I would still avoid doing any floating point arithmetic and let the extraction from float32 do the actual conversion from binary data to an Erlang float.

Comment: I do not agree with you, sub normal float represent roughly 3% of the number you can code with float16, it is not really a corner case.The closest to 0 normal number you can encode is 6.103515625e-5 which is not that small. Then without taking care of  the 0 and the sub normal cases, you think that you get a valid result, but it has an error up to 51200% (even infinity since 0 is converted into 3.0547310-5).

Answer (score 2):

There is no support for 16 bit floats. If you want collect and works on float coming from another system (via a file for example) then you can easily convert this float to the representation used in your VM.

First read the file and extract the float16 as a 2 bytes binary, and call this conversion function:

```
-module (float16).

-export([conv_16_to_vm/1]).

% conv_16_to_vm(binary) with binary is a 16 bit float representation
conv_16_to_vm(<<S:1,E:5,M:10>>)->
    conv(S,E,M).

conv(_,0,0) -> 0.0;
conv(_,31,_) -> {error,nan_or_qnan_or_infinity};
% Sign management
conv(1,E,M) -> -conv(0,E,M);
% sub normal floats
conv(0,0,M) -> M/(1 bsl 24);
% normal floats
conv(0,E,M) when E < 25 -> (1024 + M)/(1 bsl (25-E));
conv(0,25,M) -> (1024 + M);
conv(0,E,M) -> (1024 + M)*(1 bsl (E-25)).
```

I used the definition provided by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format) and you can test it:

```
1> c(float16).                      
{ok,float16}
2> float16:conv_16_to_vm(<<0,1>>).      % 0 00000 0000000001
5.960464477539063e-8
3> float16:conv_16_to_vm(<<3,255>>).    % 0 00011 1111111111
6.097555160522461e-5
4> float16:conv_16_to_vm(<<4,0>>).      % 0 00100 0000000000
6.103515625e-5
5> float16:conv_16_to_vm(<<123,255>>).  % 0 11110 1111111111
65504
6> float16:conv_16_to_vm(<<60,0>>).     % 0 01111 0000000000
1.0
7> float16:conv_16_to_vm(<<60,1>>).     % 0 01111 0000000001
1.0009765625
8> float16:conv_16_to_vm(<<59,255>>).   % 0 01110 1111111111
0.99951171875
8> float16:conv_16_to_vm(<<53,85>>).    % 0 01101 0101010101
0.333251953125
```

As you should expect, the traditional problem or "rounding" is much more visible.